# Keyboard disappear automatically

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I have a little problem with the notific of keyboard disappear, I add the observer:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidDisappear:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

The add the method:

```
- (void) keyboardDidDisappear:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"disappear");
}
```

In my application I have some button, on click it show two uitextfield with this method:

```
    - (void) showFieldStoryView:(id)sender {

    if (storyContentView.hidden == NO) {

        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        buttonTag = [button tag];
        int indexArray = buttonTag - 1;

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [arrayPunteggi objectAtIndex:indexArray];

        [fieldUno removeFromSuperview];
        [fieldDue removeFromSuperview];

        [fieldUno setHidden:YES];
        [fieldDue setHidden:YES];

        [storyContentView addSubview:fieldUno];
        [storyContentView addSubview:fieldDue];

        [fieldUnoAccusi removeFromSuperview];
        [fieldDueAccusi removeFromSuperview];

        [fieldUnoAccusi setHidden:YES];
        [fieldDueAccusi setHidden:YES];

        [labelPunti removeFromSuperview];
        [labelAccusi removeFromSuperview];
        [labelPunti setHidden:YES];
        [labelAccusi setHidden:YES];
        [storyContentView addSubview:labelPunti];
        [storyContentView addSubview:labelAccusi];

        if (fieldUno.isFirstResponder) {
            point = CGPointMake(0,button.frame.origin.y);
        }
        else {
            [fieldUno becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that every time I click on this button I see on console the log disappear, and the strange thins is that the keyboard is always show oh the screen, where is the problem?

Comment: still didn't get your question very well what exactly you want to achieve, but I would say please check [**this**](http://www.rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/handling-soft-keypad-in-iphone-tutorial.html) may help you

Comment: you check this link..i think it may help you..http://www.purenewbie.com/?p=202